# Solidity finds eth price but its realy big

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, chainlink

This script gives me some random like a number and not real eth price? the price that is outputting is 38598000000?!

```
  AggregatorInterface internal ref;
  // For ETH-USD on ropsten, input the address:
  // 0x8468b2bDCE073A157E560AA4D9CcF6dB1DB98507
  address _aggregator = 0x8468b2bDCE073A157E560AA4D9CcF6dB1DB98507;
  string toni;
  constructor() public {
    
    ref = AggregatorInterface(_aggregator);
    
  }
    int256 price;

  function getLatestAnswer() public view returns (int256) {
    return ref.latestAnswer();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Chainlink's Ropsten price feed contract is no longer in use.

Ropsten doesn't appear to be one of their supported test networks - I would suggest using [Kovan or Rinkeby](https://docs.chain.link/docs/ethereum-addresses). (The examples in the docs all use Kovan.)

Kovan:

- https://docs.chain.link/docs/ethereum-addresses#kovan
- Address: [0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331#readContract)
- `latestAnswer`: 175903771290 (i.e. $1759.03771290)

Rinkeby:

- https://docs.chain.link/docs/ethereum-addresses#rinkeby
- Address: [0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e)
- `latestAnswer`: 175394117980

Comment: is there any chance i can get just 1753

Comment: can i get frist 4 numbers

Comment: Why do you only want 4 digits? To display to the user?

Comment: I would recommend keeping all the digits so that you don't lose precision. Then on your front end you could divide by 1 x 10^8 and use `.toFixed(2)` (if you're using Javascript).

Comment: Im short on time can i only display first 4 digits because user needs to give input nad it will not give to system 175311231231 it will give 1753 only

Comment: so int256 price = ref.latestAnswer(); = is only 4 digits long